# ng start - Unknown option: '--inspect-brk'

Tags: node.js, angular, debugging

I have been trying to debug a `Hello World` Angular CLI application with IntelliJ 2018, but I am running in some difficulties and cannot find a solution for it. Initially when I ran the option `ng start` from IntelliJ to Debug, ot returned that it needed  the `%NODE_DEBUG_OPTION%` in the `pacjage.json` file, so I made this change:

```
"scripts": {     
    "start": "ng %NODE_DEBUG_OPTION% serve",
}
```

And ran the Debug again, but now it returns the error `Unknown option: '--inspect-brk'` and still have not found a solution for it. What exactly I am missing with this configuration?

Thank you.

Comment: what node version you are using?

Comment: @VishalRajole v10.13.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this will work for you

```
"start": "node %NODE_DEBUG_OPTION% ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve"
```

Comment: Hello @yurzui, thank you for your response. I applied your suggestion and now it says `Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:41132/9859a066-b570-4515-814b-46edc791a8d9`, what exactly is that address for? and how do I place breakpoints in the `Typescript` code on `Intellij`? The breakpoints are not being hit.

Comment: @JoeAlmore please follow this -> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-javascript-debugger.html